Unity искажает дочерние объекты
Недавно начал изучать Unity и столкнулся с такой проблемой: При перетаскивании, скажем Object1, в ветку Object2 (то есть делаем Object1 дочерним Object2), Object1 искажается. Модель делал в программе Blender и выставил для всех объектов Scale = 1 1 1.
Фиолетовые кнопки - это кнопки управления башней(MainBase), они на данный момент никак не запрограммированы и не были трансформированы в самой Unity.
Скрины
До того как перетащил MainPlate в MainBase

После того как перетащил MainPlate в MainBase

На скринах видно как преобразовалась модель после её перетаскивания, её слегка "повело").
Буду рад помощи!

Unity3D не виноват, ничего подобного не делает. Scale у MineBase явно не 1, он вытянут вдоль.

В иерархии Unity учитывается базовый Scale объектов для всех вложенных объектов.
Если в Inspector для объекта в иерархии без вложенных child объектов, допустим куба, Scale поставить 1, 0.25,1, вложенная в неё сфера будет вытянутой и вести себя непривычно при вращении. Это связано с тем, что матрица проекции верхнего объекта будет искажать вложенные объекты в Object Space самого объекта.
